# Compute as much of a list as possible in a fixed time

Tags: haskell, time, timeout

I want to write a function that takes a time limit (in seconds) and a list, and computes as many elements of the list as possible within the time limit.

My first attempt was to first write the following function, which times a pure computation and returns the time elapsed along with the result:

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import System.CPUTime

type Time = Double

timed :: (NFData a) => a -> IO (a, Time)
timed x = do t1 <- getCPUTime
             r  <- return $!! x
             t2 <- getCPUTime
             let diff = fromIntegral (t2 - t1) / 10^12
             return (r, diff)
```

I can then define the function I want in terms of this:

```
timeLimited :: (NFData a) => Time -> [a] -> IO [a]
timeLimited remaining []     = return []
timeLimited remaining (x:xs) = if remaining < 0
    then return []
    else do
        (y,t) <- timed x
        ys    <- timeLimited (remaining - t) xs
        return (y:ys)
```

This isn't quite right though. Even ignoring timing errors and floating point errors, this approach never stops the computation of an element of the list once it has started, which means that it can (and in fact, normally will) overrun its time limit.

If instead I had a function that could short-circuit evaluation if it had taken too long:

```
timeOut :: Time -> a -> IO (Maybe (a,t))
timeOut = undefined
```

then I could write the function that I *really* want:

```
timeLimited' :: Time -> [a] -> IO [a]
timeLimited' remaining []     = return []
timeLimited' remaining (x:xs) = do
    result <- timeOut remaining x
    case result of
        Nothing    -> return []
        Just (y,t) -> do
            ys <- timeLimited' (remaining - t) xs
            return (y:ys)
```

My questions are:

1. How do I write `timeOut`?
2. Is there a better way to write the function `timeLimited`, for example, one that doesn't suffer from accumulated floating point error from adding up time differences multiple times?

Comment: Can you not run two threads where one thread counts down the time and kills the computation thread once your time limit has been reached?

Comment: Maybe. I've not written very much concurrent code in Haskell. How would it be able to return the partially evaluated list?

Comment: I would probably put the list into a TVar and cons every new node to it. Just saw that STM.TVar has a function called `registerDelay` that also may be helpful for synchronizing two threads.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example I was able to cook up using some of the suggestions above.  I've not done huge amounts of testing to ensure work is cut off exactly when the timer runs out, but based on the docs for [`timeout`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Timeout.html), this should work for all things not using FFI.

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.DeepSeq
import System.Timeout

type Time = Int

-- | Compute as many items of a list in given timeframe (microseconds)
--   This is done by running a function that computes (with `force`)
--   list items and pushed them onto a `TVar [a]`.  When the requested time
--   expires, ghc will terminate the execution of `forceIntoTVar`, and we'll
--   return what has been pushed onto the tvar.
timeLimited :: (NFData a) => Time -> [a] -> IO [a]
timeLimited t xs = do
    v <- newTVarIO []
    _ <- timeout t (forceIntoTVar xs v)
    readTVarIO v 

-- | Force computed values into given tvar
forceIntoTVar :: (NFData a) => [a] -> TVar [a] -> IO [()]
forceIntoTVar xs v = mapM (atomically . modifyTVar v . forceCons) xs

-- | Returns function that does actual computation and cons' to tvar value
forceCons :: (NFData a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
forceCons x = (force x:)
```

Now let's try it on something costly:

```
main = do
    xs <- timeLimited 100000 expensiveThing   -- run for 100 milliseconds
    print $ length $ xs  -- how many did we get?

-- | Some high-cost computation
expensiveThing :: [Integer]
expensiveThing = sieve [2..]
  where
      sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

Compiled and run with `time`, it seems to work (obviously there is some overhead outside the timed portion, but I'm at roughly 100ms:

```
$ time ./timeLimited
1234
./timeLimited  0.10s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 0.112 total
```

Also, something to note about this approach; since I'm enclosing the entire operation of running the computations and pushing them onto the tvar inside one call to `timeout`, some time here is likely lost in creating the return structure, though I'm assuming (if your computations are costly) it won't account or much of your overall time.

**Update**

Now that I've had some time to think about it, due to Haskell's laziness, I'm not 100% positive the note above (about time-spent creating the return structure) is correct; either way, let me know if this is not precise enough for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it looks very promising. There seems to be a snag - if I run this (in GHCi) then I get some output list `x`. I can run `length x` and get an answer, but if I try to inspect the *elements* of `x` then the interpreter hangs. Do you see this behaviour as well?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, I don't, but I'm just using this primes list I've defined in my example.  Running `timeLimited 10 expensiveThing` in ghci yields `[67,61,59,53,47,43,41,37,31,29,23,19,17,13,11,7,5,3,2]`.  Are you testing this exact case, or with your real computations?  Is there something different about them?  Maybe try for a shorter period of time.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Also, not sure that it matters, but I'm running ghc 7.0.4

Comment: I was testing it by computing a list of Fibonacci numbers, but I've now tested it with your example and the same thing happens - if less than the entire list is computed, then the interpreter hangs when I try to look at the result (using ghci 7.4.1). I've now fixed it up using `deepseq` to compute values outside of the `TVar` monad, and that seems to work - will update my question with the code once I've tidied it up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor So `forceCons` now looks more like this? `forceCons x = deepseq x (x:)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement `timeOut` with the type you gave using [`timeout`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Timeout.html#v%3atimeout) and [`evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v%3aevaluate). It looks something like this (I've omitted the part that computes how much time is left -- use `getCurrentTime` or similar for that):

```
timeoutPure :: Int -> a -> IO (Maybe a)
timeoutPure t a = timeout t (evaluate a)
```

If you want more forcing than just weak-head normal form, you can call this with an already-seq'd argument, e.g. `timeoutPure (deepseq v)` instead of `timeoutPure v`.

Comment: This approach is useful, but doesn't return the partial solutions after the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I would use two threads together with TVars and raise an exception (that causes every ongoing transaction to be rolled back) in the computation thread when the timeout has been reached:

```
forceIntoTVar :: (NFData a) => [a] -> TVar [a] -> IO [()]
forceIntoTVar xs v = mapM (atomically . modifyTVar v . forceCons) xs

-- | Returns function that does actual computation and cons' to tvar value
forceCons :: (NFData a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
forceCons x = (force x:)

main = do

  v <- newTVarIO []
  tID <- forkIO $ forceIntoTVar args v
  threadDelay 200
  killThread tID
  readTVarIO v
```

In this example you (may) need to adjust forceIntoTVar a bit so that e.g. the list nodes are **NOT** computet inside the atomic transaction but first computed and then a atomic transaction is started to cons them onto the list.

In any case, when the exception is raised the ongoing transaction is rolled back or the ongoing computation is stopped before the result is consed to the list and that is what you want.

What you need to consider is that when the individual computations to prepare a node run with high frequency then this example is probably very costly compared to not using STM.

Comment: I got this to work once I'd modified `forceIntoTVar` to use `deepseq`, so that the nodes are fully computed outside of the transaction (as you suggested). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor What is the reason here to use `deepeseq` and not bang patterns?

Comment: I don't know how to use bang patterns :)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I personally prefer smaller binaries before bigger binaries. IMHO bang patterns should produce the same but result in smaller binaries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is it your opinion that bang patterns produce smaller binaries than using `seq`/`deepseq` and the like, or is it a fact? I tend to prefer code clarity over compact binaries, so I'll have to look at bang patterns to see if they make the intent any clearer.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor It's a language option that saves altogether dozens (100s?) of lines of code. You can easily test it.

Comment: I've had a quick look and they certainly look useful. Thanks!